# stack with with array passing from function in C

Tags: c, arrays, function

How can I use information from array that will be passed from function?

```
 #include <stdio.h>

 double get_number(double[]);

 main {

 double x, z[100];
 char m;

 do { 
 x = get_number[z];
 printf("More numbers?");
 scanf (" %c", &m);

      }
 while ((m == 'Y')||(m == 'y'))
}


double get_number(double arr[])
{
    printf ("Please enter number :   ?");
    scanf("%d", &arr);
    return arr;
}
```

For example 
when user press couple times Y and filled array with two or three numbers.
How can I operate with those numbers? count them or just show them.

Comment: Please format your code. Look around this website to see how it's done.

Comment: What exactly is your question? Do you want us to help with your various compile errors?

Comment: this code is confused for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a for() loop.

```
for (int i = 0; i < array_size; i++) {
     printf ("Number at index %d: %f", i, arr[i]);
}
```

Of course, you need to know the size beforehand. And don't use scanf() with an array like that, why not have:

```
double get_input ()
{
    double number = 0;

    printf ("Please enter number: ");
    scanf ("%d", &number);

    return number;
}
```

Define your array length to be something fixed:

```
#define ARRAY_SIZE 1024
```

if you need more than that, increase the value or consider using a list structure.

Hope this helps

**EDIT**

If you want to have a sum, for example, you need to first initialize the array:

```
double array[ARRAY_SIZE];
for (int i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; i++) array[i] = 0;
```

Then you get the input:

```
char input;
int counter = 0;
do {
    if (counter > ARRAY_SIZE) break; // dont cause a segmentation fault

    scanf ("%c", &input);
    double number = get_input();
    array[counter] = number;

} while (input == 'Y' || input == 'y');
```

Then when thats done, just go through the array and sum it up:

```
int sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; i++) {
    sum += array[i];
}
```

Comment: sorry, maybe my code is have some problems right here, but I just need to know the idea of how to operate with array that I get from function, for example if user filled my array with number 1, then number 2, and then number 3, and next time when user ask if to continue he pressed No, and want to know how to operate with those numbers from array?

for example to count 1+2+3; and do printf("the sum of your array is 6");

Comment: vanneto, thank you very much, you helped me a lot, you make my day better.